# How to edit hidden forms in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNeIE.png)

I want to change "Vendor" and replace it with "Host". It is in the contact form the plugin used is contact form 7. The name of the form is "custom-register-form" but I cannot find that form in my forms list.
I believe the theme developer does not want the user to edit this field.
(I have purchased the theme from ThemeForest)
theme URL: https://ovatheme.com/meup

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a form in a custom theme by doing at least one of the following (ordered from easiest to hardest):

1. Using the personalize sub-menu in the appearance menu - if the form
   can be edited from there.
2. Using the theme options menu - if there is any and if the option to
   edit that form is available.
3. By creating a new sub-theme based on the original theme and editing
   the source-code in there - some theme developers can assist you with
   that.

You can also contact the theme developer to enable you to use method 1 or 2 in the following versions of the theme.